# JDBC connection is not working with Microsoft Access in corejava

Tags: java, database, ms-access, jdbc, connection

When I execute the program it will execute the catch() part . I have also name the database file as "Database1" also created its source as "Database1", table named "Table1" contain 3 fields of text . Java version and JDBC driver both are 32-bit please help.

```
import java.sql.*;

class  Database
{
    // 3 VARIABLES we declare 
    Connection con; // Get the connection to our database
    Statement st;   // Access to ur tables inside our database
    ResultSet rs;   // Access to records in our database

public Database(){

    connect();

}
public void connect(){
// To develop Connection
//Every SQL connection throws an exception which we have to handle

try{
    // Name for driver      
    String driver = "sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver"; // hold driver for database in this jdbc
    //load class
    Class.forName(driver);

    // Name for Database
    String db = "jdbc:odbc:Database1";
    // Set Connection
    con = DriverManager.getConnection(db);
    st = con.createStatement();

    String sql = "SELECT * from Table1";
    rs = st.executeQuery(sql);

    while(rs.next())
    {

        String fname = rs.getString("FName");
        String lname = rs.getString("LName");
        String age   = rs.getString("Age");

        System.out.println(fname+""+lname+""+age+"");

    }


}catch(Exception ex){

System.out.println("Exception Catch is running");
}

}

public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    new Database();
}
```

}

Comment: you can print error with " ex.printStackTrace() " and see what is causing the exception.

Comment: What is "corejava"? And what Java version are you using. FYI: The JdbcOdbcDriver is no longer available in Java 8.